# rails footer not sticking at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have this

```
<body>
<% if params[:action] == "show" && params[:controller] == "events" %>
  <div class="loading-spinner" style="z-index:200000;"></div>
  <% end %>
  <div id="wrap">
    <header>
      <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
    </header>
    <!-- <aside class="image-bg-fixed-height"></aside> -->

    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 100px">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
          <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <%= yield %>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

</body>
</html>
```

For some reason i have the whitespace bug underneath the footer. How do i get rid of this?

I got the footer code from here

http://tutorialzine.com/2015/01/freebie-5-responsive-footer-templates/

Which doesn't work here either. Maybe something wrong with the code?

Thanks

Sam

Comment: Could you post an image of your footer, as well as style code for your layout and footer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe remove this rule :

**CSS**

```
@media (max-height: 800px){
footer {
    position: fixed;
}
}
```